# how put logged user name/email with user data in the Firestore KOTLIN

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app which creates schedules.
I create schedule with date and save into Firestore, then I list on my recycler view, it is working fine.
Now want save this schedule with the current user which created this schedule. anyone can help me.. Thank you..

below my codes explained

here I get time from the time picker.

class CreateScheduleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
var dateformater = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/YYYY", Locale.UK)
var timeFormater = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.UK)
lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_schedule)

    var dateFrom = et_from_date
    var dateTo = et_to_date


    dateFrom.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
    dateTo.showSoftInputOnFocus = false



    fun showDate() {
        val now = Calendar.getInstance()
        val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(
            this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                val selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance()

                selectedDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

                var date = dateformater.format(selectedDate.time)

                dateFrom.setText(date).toString()
                dateTo.setText(date).toString()
            },
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )

        datePicker.show()
    } // showDate end
```

```
here I get the picked values and save to the Firestore.






    fun saveData() {
                var setDateFrom = et_from_date.text.toString()         
                var setDateTo = et_to_date.text.toString()         
                var map = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()

                map["dateFrom"] = setDateFrom
                map["dateTo"] = setDateTo   

                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                        .collection("schedules")
                        .document()
                        .set(map)

                openHomeActivity()
            }// saveData() end


[here is my data saved in Firestore][1]

[and here is recycler view list, NOTE THERE IS NO LOGGED USER ][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrFjR.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhxbC.png
```

Answer (score 0):

*correction > *the app makes schedules *

Comment: You can use the 'edit' button to make any changes/corrections to your question

Comment: Thank you I have jus figured out.